# Tearing NVIDIA GTX 1050 in laptop MSI GL-72 kubuntu - haves also intel graphics

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, xorg, intel, tearing

I can't remove nvidia tearing with laptop msi-gl72.
I installed nvidia driver 375.66 in kubuntu and works but haves screen tearing.
In other computers i remove the tearing with a sh file.
The sh file not works with the laptop screen.

I try this sh file.

```
nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="eDP-1-1:1920x1080_60 +0+0 { ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On }"
```

The screen not flashes and nothing happens when I run the sh. The tearing is not disappearing like in other computers.

In the monitors app I can see the screen is `eDP-1-1`. In other computers this name changes. (`HDMI-0` , etc)

I not get how to remove the tearing. If I use intel graphics instead nvidia there is no tearing but the system hangs sometimes and it would ruin performance for linux games.

I want to remove the nvidia tearing.

```
My xorg.conf is:
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "modesetting"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option "AccelMethod" "None"
    Option "TearFree" "true"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
    Option "metamodes" "eDP-1-1:1920x1080_60 +0+0 { ForceCompositionPipeline = on } "
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
    Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
    Option "TearFree" "true"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
    Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
    Option "metamodes" "eDP-1-1:1920x1080_60 +0+0 { 
ForceCompositionPipeline = on } "

EndSection
```

I want to remove nvidia tearing.
If I connect external monitor to HDMI happens the same problem. I can't remove tearing.

I got system stable with intel graphics selected on nvidia prime using the most recent nvidia driver of graphics ppa.
This not will be good for gaming but desktop works good with youtube 60fps.
I will wait for nvidia prime synchronization fixes in the future.

For enable intel with no crash I enabled secure boot in bios

Comment: Where did you get the (sh) command from? It may work to modify it to better suit your computer (the interface will be different and the screen is probably a different resolution)

Comment: I describe how to enable PRIME Synchronization in this thread. For 16.04 it works fine with the xserver-xorg-core-hwe-16.04 package that will be coming soon (- currently in -proposed) https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2365449 Note that thread doesn't explain how to get the -proposed HWE now, reasonably simple with synaptic

Comment: The TearFree  Intel option wouldn't work with modesetting, it  would with SNA but that's been disabled in Ubuntu.